# Pass argument with boost::bind not working

Tags: c++, boost

I have this code that I need to pass on a `struct` variable through `boost:bind`

```
client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
            boost::asio::ssl::context& context,
            const std::string& server, const std::string& path, const std::string& port, RESTClient::response& resp)
            : resolver_(io_service),
            socket_(io_service, context)
        {
            resp.body = "first!"; // Works fine
            std::ostream request_stream(&request_);
            request_stream << "GET " << path << " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
            request_stream << "Host: " << server << "\r\n";
            request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
            request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

            tcp::resolver::query query(server, port);
            resolver_.async_resolve(query,
                boost::bind(&client::handle_resolve, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::iterator,
                resp));
        }
```

However here I added a change which does not work:

```
void handle_resolve(const boost::system::error_code& err,
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator, RESTClient::response &resp)
{
    (&resp)->body = "Haloo!!!"; // not working
}
```

In what way that the `body` can be set after the `boost::bind` call?

Comment: Why on earth are you using `(&resp)->body` instead of `resp.body`?

Comment: @Praetorian He probably overloaded `operator&` with a different semantic than the one expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bind` copies all of its arguments by default. From the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.purpose.using_bind_with_functions_and_fu):

> The arguments that bind takes are **copied** and held internally by the returned function object. For example, in the following code:
>
> ```
> int i = 5;
> bind(f, i, _1);
> ```
>
> a copy of the value of `i` is stored into the function object. `boost::ref` and `boost::cref` can be used to make the function object store a reference to an object, rather than a copy

Which in this case would be:

```
boost::bind(&client::handle_resolve, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::iterator,
            boost::ref(resp)));
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I'm getting error C2039: 'result_type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''

Comment: Can you share the exact code that triggers that, @xybrek?

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279373/error-c2039-result-type-is-not-a-member-of-global-namespace