# error C2039: 'result_type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013

My app is throwing this error:

```
error C2039: 'result_type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
```

for this code:

```
void handle_read_headers(const boost::system::error_code& err, RESTClient::response& resp)
{
    if (!err)
    {
        // Process the response headers.
        std::istream response_stream(&response_);
        std::string header;
        while (std::getline(response_stream, header) && header != "\r")
            std::cout << header << "\n";
        std::cout << "\n";

        // Write whatever content we already have to output.
        if (response_.size() > 0)
            std::cout << &response_;

        (&resp)->body = "Yehey!!!";

        // Start reading remaining data until EOF.
        boost::asio::async_read(socket_, response_,
        boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
        boost::bind(&client::handle_read_content, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::ref(resp)));

    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << err << "\n";
    }
}
```

The "bound" function looks like this:

```
void handle_read_content(const boost::system::error_code& err, RESTClient::response& resp){}
```

What could be wrong in my code?

**Update:**

I was able to compile the code with these changes

[image]

Comment: Which line throws the error???

Comment: Yes, but the compiler will also tell you which instantiation of which a template *in your code* led to this error.

Comment: As a data point: gcc 4.9 compiles it fine. Clang 3.5 as well

Comment: PS. That's not a recursive call. The "recursive" call will be from a completion handler. So it's really sequential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this documentation page ReadHandler needs to take and error code *as well as* the number of bytes transferred.

It might be that MSVC is more picky/sensitive about the missing placeholders when invoking a bind expression.¹

Try adding the placeholder parameter to the bind:

```
// Start reading remaining data until EOF.
boost::asio::async_read(socket_, response_,
        boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
        boost::bind(&client::handle_read_content, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
            boost::ref(resp)));
```

And obviously to the handler function itself too:

```
void handle_read_content(const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t bytes_transferred, RESTClient::response& resp){}
```

### Update

I have spent unreasonable amounts of effort (thanks to @qballer, @nab, and others on the live feed too!) to reproduce this in Visual Studio and got this:

[image]

For the record: that was

- Win32
- Boost 1_58_0
- openssl-1.0.2c-i386-win32
- Visual Studio 2013 Update 4

---

¹ in fact I've sometimes noticed that Asio accepts slightly different signatures for handler functions using GCC (my preferred compiler). I've always wondered whether that is a feature, or perhaps a bug?

Comment: even just adding bytes_transferred causes the error to be thrown

Comment: FTR it's not an error that gets 'thrown' (exceptions get thrown, and that would be at runtime. You have a compilation error). If you add a SSCCE I might look at it with MSVC

Comment: Ok I will upload to Github after all this will be a opensource project

Comment: uhoh. I'm not sure that will fit my definition of "Small Self-contained" :)

Comment: It just a small code here: http://bit.ly/1gnemqG    this is working version that I commented out stuff in the 'void handle_read_content' which should receive the placeholder parameters which is causing some error

Comment: @xybrek Now, I wonder why you assume I make changes: **[proof after compilation](http://i.imgur.com/xpcu34t.png)**. I didn't. Updated the answer with details, btw

Comment: I was able to compile earlier too, but with code changes, see my updated answer (that's why I was wondering why it worked when you did not changed anything)