# How to use boost::hash to get the file content hash?

Tags: c++, boost, hash

Is it possible to use boost:hash function to generate a file content hash with fixed length like MD5?

Is there a quick solution for this?

If not, what is the simplest way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Boost doesn't implement MD5. Use a crypto/hash library for this.

CryptoC++ is nice in my experience.

OpenSSL implements all the popular digests, here's a sample that uses OpenSSL:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/057279d40cca7113)</kbd>**

```
#include <openssl/md5.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

// Print the MD5 sum as hex-digits.
void print_md5_sum(unsigned char* md) {
    for(unsigned i=0; i <MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(md[i]);
    }
}

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    using namespace std;
    vector<string> const args(argv+1, argv+argc);

    for (auto& fname : args) {

        MD5_CTX ctx;
        MD5_Init(&ctx);

        ifstream ifs(fname, std::ios::binary);

        char file_buffer[4096];
        while (ifs.read(file_buffer, sizeof(file_buffer)) || ifs.gcount()) {
            MD5_Update(&ctx, file_buffer, ifs.gcount());
        }
        unsigned char digest[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {};
        MD5_Final(digest, &ctx);

        print_md5_sum(digest);
        std::cout << "\t" << fname << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is linux only, that's the problem for me.

Comment: @joker Both crypto c++ and OpenSsl are available on windows.(and probably most platforms you can dream of)

Comment: your code (and any other sample) uses linux headers, Could you show windows example if so? Will be fantastic

Comment: @Joker. Really, those headers mostly deal with reading the file. You can probably deal with that some other way? Here's ***[a delightfully C++-ified version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/057279d40cca7113)***. You can see me refactor that in [this live-stream recording](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/c-ifying-openssl-md5-code-sample/).

Comment: I don't currently have access to a windows dev machine. You can, however, see me configuring VS2013 to compile against OpenSSL here: [live-stream recording¹](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/unlabeled-2/) when answering [this older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279373/q/31280704#31280704). I happened to do the whole dnace of downloading OpenSSL, creating the import libraries, configuring include and library dirs and whatnot. So if you get stuck, and have the patience, you could watch that ¹ ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83158/discussion-between-sehe-and-joker).

Answer (score 2):

boot has such functionality. At lest now: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/uuid/doc/uuid.html

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/uuid/detail/md5.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/hex.hpp>

using boost::uuids::detail::md5;

std::string toString(const md5::digest_type &digest)
{
    const auto charDigest = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&digest);
    std::string result;
    boost::algorithm::hex(charDigest, charDigest + sizeof(md5::digest_type), std::back_inserter(result));
    return result;
}

int main ()
{
    std::string s;

    while(std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
        md5 hash;
        md5::digest_type digest;

        hash.process_bytes(s.data(), s.size());
        hash.get_digest(digest);

        std::cout << "md5(" << s << ") = " << toString(digest) << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CJ0MMunEhYCRe6Cd)

Comment: One need to pay attention to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68924521/136285