# how to calculate md5 of a file using boost?

Tags: c++, boost, md5

I need to calculate md5 of a file, but I don't want to link my project with the OpenSSL library for some reason.
For me one of the best solutions is make it via boost library.
I found next sample:

```
#include <boost/md5.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

std::cout << boost::md5("message").hex_str_value();

boost::md5(std::ifstream("file.txt")).hex_str_value();
```

but unfortunately there is no `boost/md5.hpp` header in current boost version (1.68.0/1.69.0).

Can somebody tell me how to implement the sample below using current boost version 1.69.0?

I hope this post will help everyone who will search it as me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use boost::hash to get the file content hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383580/how-to-use-boosthash-to-get-the-file-content-hash)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to use boost 1.66.0 or later version to avail this functionality.
Small changes to ToString() method in Marek R code as it generates invalid checksum.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/uuid/detail/md5.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/hex.hpp>

using boost::uuids::detail::md5;

std::string toString(const md5::digest_type &digest)
{
    const auto intDigest = reinterpret_cast<const int*>(&digest);
    std::string result;
    boost::algorithm::hex(intDigest, intDigest + (sizeof(md5::digest_type)/sizeof(int)), std::back_inserter(result));
    return result;
}

int main ()
{
    std::string s;

    while(std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
        md5 hash;
        md5::digest_type digest;

        hash.process_bytes(s.data(), s.size());
        hash.get_digest(digest);

        std::cout << "md5(" << s << ") = " << toString(digest) << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "charDigest" should be "intDigest" in your code.

Answer (score 4):

after boost 1.71 boost/uuid/detail/md5.hpp can not calculate md5 correctly,
for details can reference https://github.com/boostorg/uuid/issues/111
,so boost don't has a md5 now.

paste what links sa:

> Boost.UUID does not provide a public component for MD5 generation. What you're using is an implementation detail of a name generator, it does not have to give a compliant MD5, as other tools do.

Comment: Reading the link makes clear the problem, but answers on SO are usually more helpful if they're not entirely dependent on an external link. Can you add information from the linked issue here to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

boost has such functionality:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/uuid/detail/md5.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/hex.hpp>

using boost::uuids::detail::md5;

std::string toString(const md5::digest_type &digest)
{
    const auto charDigest = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&digest);
    std::string result;
    boost::algorithm::hex(charDigest, charDigest + sizeof(md5::digest_type), std::back_inserter(result));
    return result;
}

int main ()
{
    std::string s;

    while(std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
        md5 hash;
        md5::digest_type digest;

        hash.process_bytes(s.data(), s.size());
        hash.get_digest(digest);

        std::cout << "md5(" << s << ") = " << toString(digest) << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[`Live Example`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CJ0MMunEhYCRe6Cd)

Comment: Using something from "detail" isn't that great, is it?